# List view in SwiftUI takes up entire screen height

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, swiftui-list

In SwiftUI, list view by default takes up entire height of the screen and pushes other elements/views to the bottom of the screen. But I want to append some elements/views where the list items exactly end.

[image: List view having 10 items]

Comment: For those looking for an answer, I have answered similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837419/9607863) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928117/9607863) which may help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add spacer() at appropriate places in the VStack or try something like below:

```
VStack {
            CustomView1()
            List {
                Section(header: HeaderView(), footer: FooterView())
                {
                    ForEach(viewModel.permissions) { permission in
                        CustomeView2()
                }
                    GeneralView()//add the views at the end of list items
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, including all the buttons and list in one section worked. Spacer does not work in this case, I have tried before.