# Push list with 4 rows to bottom

Tags: swiftui

I want to have this list at the bottom of the screen. I know that there are only 4 Rows (or 5). I tried to use `UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = …` 
But the value depends on the screenHeight, the rowHeight and the safeArea. When I tried to use this after `onAppeared()` the largeTitle changed to inLine. I need it because then I need GeometryReader for the inset and the listrow. I also set the TableView to `UiTableView.appearance().scrollingEnabled = false`
I don’t know how to archive it. I would like to have the title always large and the screen not scrollable.
Thanks for any help.

```
var body:some View{
    NavigationView{
       List{
           Text(„hi“)
           Text(„hi“)
           Text(„hi“)
           Text(„hi“)
       }
       .navigationBarTitle(„Hi“, displayMode: .large)
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836342/spacer-not-working-with-form-inside-a-vstack/68837419#68837419) for a bunch of answers. The issue you are having is that a `List` will take up the entire view by its nature.

Comment: See *Reverse* variant in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030, it might be helpful.

Comment: @Yrb Wow a link to my answer :D

Comment: That's what this is all about...